# Fetching all the array elements using rs.next()

Tags: java, sql, arrays, database, iterator

I'm having a problem fetching data from database.
I'm trying to fetch the list of array.

But my problem is that i can only get the last element of the array maybe because it overwrites the previous one.

Here's my code.

```
                 String sql;
                 sql = "select * from NM_PROPERTIES_LOADER";
                 ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
                 String prop_name = null;
                 String prop_value = null;
                 PropertyData reader = new PropertyData();

                 while(rs.next()){
                     prop_name = rs.getString("prop_name");
                     prop_value = rs.getString("prop_value");
                     reader.setPropName(prop_name);
                     reader.setPropValue(prop_value);
                     ..//other setter..  


                     System.out.println(prop_name + " " + prop_value);
                 }
                 prop.add(reader);
```

In my sysout I can retrieve all the datas. but on my page only the last element is retrieved. Here's my dao class.

```
public class PropertyData {

private int id;
private String propName;
private String propValue;
private String engineName;
private String desc;
private Date createdAt;
private String createdBy;
private Date updatedAt;
private String updatedBy;



public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getPropName() {
    return propName;
}
public void setPropName(String propName) {
    this.propName = propName;
}
public String getPropValue() {
    return propValue;
}
public void setPropValue(String propValue) {
    this.propValue = propValue;
}
public String getEngineName() {
    return engineName;
}
public void setEngineName(String engineName) {
    this.engineName = engineName;
}
public String getDesc() {
    return desc;
}
public void setDesc(String desc) {
    this.desc = desc;
}
public Date getCreatedAt() {
    return createdAt;
}
public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
    this.createdAt = createdAt;
}
public String getCreatedBy() {
    return createdBy;
}
public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
    this.createdBy = createdBy;
}
public Date getUpdatedAt() {
    return updatedAt;
}
public void setUpdatedAt(Date updatedAt) {
    this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
}
public String getUpdatedBy() {
    return updatedBy;
}
public void setUpdatedBy(String updatedBy) {
    this.updatedBy = updatedBy;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In every iteration of the loop, you overwrite the content of `reader`.
You want to create `reader` inside the loop, not outside,
and also do `prop.add(reader)` inside the loop, not outside.

Like this:

```
 String sql = "select * from NM_PROPERTIES_LOADER";
 ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

 while(rs.next()) {
     PropertyData reader = new PropertyData();
     String name = rs.getString("prop_name");
     String value = rs.getString("prop_value");
     reader.setPropName(name);
     reader.setPropValue(value);

     // other setter calls..  

     prop.add(reader);
 }
```

Comment: I already tried this. it displayed the length of the array. in my case 36 rows. but all rows displayed is just my last element. my last element is "password" so i have 36 rows of "password".

Comment: I don't see how that's possible with `PropertyData reader = new PropertyData();` inside the loop. If that's really the case, then there is another problem elsewhere.

Comment: ohhh.. forgot to put the PropertyData reader = new PropertyData(); inside the loop. my bad. now it's working. thanks mate!